# Adding a ActionPerformed Array to a String Array

Tags: java

Before you guys ask, yes I've searched online for the answer, but everything I found just leaves a lil confuse and nothing is recent so asking in those forums won't really help.

My problems is this:

I have an array that holds my name for a menu.

```
String[] fontColor = new String[] {"Red", "Blue", "Green"};

for (int i = 0; i < fontColors.length; i++) {
     JMenuItem fontC = new JMenuItem(fontColors[i]);
     fontC.addActionListener(new fontColorAction());
     changeFontColor.add(fontC);
}
```

Then I have an array that holds my color change in a class called fontColorAction

in that class I have another array that does the same thing as my string array except all thats in the statement is textarea.setForeground(colorArr[i]);

that will set the setForeground() in order, but now how do I successfully attact the action listner in my class to my menuItems?

my class looks like this

```
private class fontColorAction implements ActionListener {
     Color[] colorArr - new Color[] {"Color.RED","Color.BLUE","Color.GREEN"};
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
          for(i = 0; i < collorArr.length; i++){
               textarea.setForeground(colorArr[i]);
          }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a color attribute to your action:

```
private class FontColorAction implements ActionListener {
     private Color color;
     public FontColorAction (Color color){
          this.color = color;
     }

     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
          textarea.setForeground(color);
     }
}
```

And initialize the actions like this:

```
 String[] fontColor = new String[] {"Red", "Blue", "Green"};
 Color[] colorArr - new Color[] {"Color.RED","Color.BLUE","Color.GREEN"};

for (int i = 0; i < fontColors.length; i++) {
     JMenuItem fontC = new JMenuItem(fontColors[i]);
     fontC.addActionListener(new fontColorAction(colorArr [i));
     changeFontColor.add(fontC);
}
```

Also, by convention java classes have their first letter in upper case ;)

Comment: thanks, that really helped me a lot. it cut down my code from 515 lines to 411 lines ;)

Answer (score 0):

The FontColorAction is listening to the actions on the muenu items. I think you problem is this loop:

```
for(i = 0; i < collorArr.length; i++){
           textarea.setForeground(colorArr[i]);
}
```

Here you are just setting the color to Color.GREEN because is the last item on the array.
If you declare i as a field it will work.

```
private class fontColorAction implements ActionListener {
     Color[] colorArr = new Color[] {"Color.RED","Color.BLUE","Color.GREEN"};
     private int colorIndex = 0;
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
          textarea.setForeground(colorArr[colorIndex]);
          colorIndex++;
          if(colorIndex==colorArr.length){
              colorIndex = 0;
          }

     }
}
```